# Outlook: When I highlight text, I can neither delete nor write over it. How do I fix this?

Tags: outlook

So I have this problem where I cannot delete or write over text. I had the same problem in Word, and I was able to fix it in options. I just sent a letter where I swapped out "March" for "Janurary" but it ended up saying "MarchJanuary" which was not that bad. Another email said "Good afternoonmorning"

Comment: Please read tour, this question belongs elsewhere like at SuperUser.com - https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking in the  File > Options > Mail > Editor Options > Advanced >  Typing replaces selected text

See if this is ticked, this should solve your issue.